# Error in text file returned with urlconnection

Tags: java, android, file, url

I am new in android so need some help please.I am writing simple test to use in my android app.
The code try to get text file from url and store in the sdcard .

In the asyntask the code is:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://sites.google.com/site/ghadeerdarwesh93/downl/gh.txt" );
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        int  totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
       Log.i("totalSize","totalSize=" + Integer.toString(totalSize));

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"gh.txt");

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength ;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        //close the output stream when complete //
        fileOutput.close();
    }
```

when it done I find gh.txt in sdcard but it is (1kb) and has unknown data .
shortly it is wrong file.

I added the permissions correctly in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem?  Is the file too short, or is it completely the wrong file?

Comment: Add a `Log` call before the `fileOutput.write` so you can see how many bytes you are (trying) to write.

Comment: You have to call fileOutput.flush() before closing it

Comment: Thanks alot.total size return -1 but I think because the response body.

Comment: The actul file contains only my name but I found these lines  and more :     HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://366e76cf-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/ghadeerdarwesh93/downl/gh.txt?attachauth=ANoY7cp57sRDDrNljTHY7VJ6BHueu8lhsDD3hNiUDzxxlxkj7TjKJjLus5ZxEAEMNTdSTMnifsa54CcfKv9DN5fnYRbMsXnAjfOc3_qH